Flowise Conversational Agent keeps repeating the response "System message should be the first one"
I have implemented a basic conversational agent in Flowise. However when I initiate a conversation with it ,the agent keep giving me the same response
I was expecting the agent to work and generate response to my question


what does your system prompt look like ?
